# TextButton's text color not changing

Tags: flutter

I added this theme for my `TextButton`.

```
textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
        style: ButtonStyle(
          shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0))),
          textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
            (Set<MaterialState> states) {
              if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed) || states.contains(MaterialState.hovered))
                return TextStyles.headline3.copyWith(
                  color: AppColors.dustyOrange,
                );
              return TextStyles.headline3;
            },
          ),
          side: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
            (Set<MaterialState> states) {
              if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed) || states.contains(MaterialState.hovered))
                return BorderSide(
                  width: 1,
                  color: AppColors.dustyOrange,
                );
              return BorderSide(width: 1, color: AppColors.white.withOpacity(0.2));
            },
          ),
        ),
      )
```

and here is my `TextButton`:

```
TextButton(
          onPressed: () => widget.onTap(),
          child: Text(widget.title, style: theme?.textTheme.headline3),
          style: theme?.textButtonTheme.style!.copyWith(
            padding: MaterialStateProperty.all(EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15, horizontal: 20)),
          )
        )
```

The problem is that when the button pressed, the style of the button is changing, but the color is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are generally three issue in your code. First, you don't need to assign `style` to the `Text` because `TextButton` itself has a `style` property. Second, you need to create a copy of `TextStyle` before you return it. And last, the `color` property needs to be changed to the `foreground` because the later gets precedence when there's a conflict between `color` and `foreground`.

Here's the minimal reproducible code:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Material(
    body: Center(
      child: Theme(
        data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
          textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
            style: ButtonStyle(
              shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0))),
              textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
                (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                  final headline3 = Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline3;
                  if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed) || states.contains(MaterialState.hovered)) {
                    final textStyle = headline3.copyWith(foreground: Paint()..color = Colors.orange);
                    return textStyle;
                  }
                  return headline3;
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        child: TextButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          style: Theme.of(context).textButtonTheme.style,
          child: Text('Button'),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Output of it

[image]